# jquery are these two formats the same?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery library which works on this form of data

```
data = [{
           label: 'IVR',
           data: dIvr
       }, {
           label: 'Agents',
           data: dAgents
       }, {
           label: 'Abandoned',
           data: dAbandoned
       }, {
           label: 'Cancelled',
           data: dCancelled
       }];
```

I need to use it so I build this function:

```
$.getJSON('url',
      { fromDate: "01-01-2014", toDate: "09-04-2014" })
       .done(function (result) {
           var data = [];
           $.each(result, function (index, value) {
               var obj = {};
               obj.label = value.Campaign;
               if (value.Count == 0) {
                   obj.data = 0;
               } else {
                   obj.data = value.SL / value.Count;
               }
               data.push(obj);
           })
    console.log(data)
```

I print the data using the `console.log` and the result is this:
[image]

are these two data formats the same? I am asking because I am getting exceptions from the library. I don't get these exceptions when I make the data manualy, but when I used the above function, I got the exception

#### for who needs the exception

it is `Cannot read property '0' of undefined` in the `jquery.flot.orderBars.js` like 79

Comment: which is the exception in detail?

Comment: Yes, that's the console's way of showing you an array of objects.

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan I edited the question and added the exception

Comment: The problem isn't your array, it's the fact that your variable is `undefined` before line 79 for some reason.

Comment: cannot read property `0` of undefined means whatever you are doing [0] on is undefined.

Comment: @Pointy so these two data are the same format right?

Comment: Yes, they are the same. you wanted an array of objects and you have an array of objects.

Comment: @KevinB the excpetion on this line `minMaxValues[0] =series[i].data[0][AxeIdx];` I know what it means but I can't change anything in the library, it is a huge one for drawing charts

Comment: That means the plugin expects `data` to be an array of arrays or objects, not a string.

Comment: So apparently `series[i].data` is undefined. That's all we can tell you.

Comment: @KevinB OMG , yes it is array, how can I forgot that

Comment: hmm... looking at it again, it could be failing either at data[0], or at data[0][AxeIdx]

Comment: @Blazemonger no no, Kevin has told me the correct thing, I have used that function before and I passed an array to it not just values.

Comment: @A.Wolff no inside the `.done` but that doens't matter, becase the problem is that I pass one value to each `data` , but i should have passed an array. KevinB helped me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the exception

```
Cannot read property '0' of undefined in the jquery.flot.orderBars.js line 79
```

and the line the exception happened on

```
minMaxValues[0] =series[i].data[0][AxeIdx];
```

`series[i]` is undefined, or `data[0]` is undefined. Most likely `data[0]` is undefined since `data` in the array of objects you are passing contains numbers instead of arrays.

Comment: I have used flot. This is correct. The entire array is called the series, so it should be fine. The error is due to the `data` properties not being arrays.

Comment: I will accpet the answer after 3 minutes

Comment: @AlexW because you used the library. please can you answer me. I have `undifined` extra colomn in my charts. always has this extrat one. why please?

Comment: @user3432257 You should open a new question. I would have to see your code to know why.

Comment: @AlexW i asked a question but not on another issue, could you check it please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23064673/flot-how-to-know-the-x-axis-points-in-dynamic-data