# flot how to know the x axis points in dynamic data

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I am using flot jquery library to draw charts.

when my chart has a specific number of columns, I can set the x values for my points.

but now I have a dynmic data. so how can I know the points of the x axis please?

for example,

```
the x axis of the first point is 1325876000000
the x axis of the second point is 1328194400000
the third is 1330360000000
the fourth is 1332838400000
```

but lets say that I will have 9 columns. how can I know the x axis for them please?

I am printing the chart in this way

```
var holder = $('#vertical-chart');

   if (holder.length) {
       $.plot(holder, data, chartOptions);
   }
```

#### the input data is like this

label: "label1"

```
data: [[1325876000000,0],[1325876000000,0],[1325876000000,0],[1325876000000,30]]
```

but now I don't know how many points in that array. it could be 11 or it could be 2

#### edit

this the chartoption

```
  chartOptions = {
           xaxis: {
               min: (new Date(2011, 11, 15)).getTime(),
               max: (new Date(2012, 04, 18)).getTime(),
               mode: "time",
               tickSize: [2, "month"],
               monthNames: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
               tickLength: 0
           },
           grid: {
               hoverable: true,
               clickable: false,
               borderWidth: 0
           },
           bars: {
               show: true,
               barWidth: 12 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 300,
               fill: true,
               lineWidth: 1,
               order: true,
               lineWidth: 0,
               fillColor: { colors: [{ opacity: 1 }, { opacity: 1 }] }
           },

           tooltip: true,
           tooltipOpts: {
               content: '%s: %y'
           },
           colors: App.chartColors
       }
```

Comment: What kind of data are you plotting? What is the source of the data? Can you provide an example of the value stored in the `data` variable?

Comment: So, it looks like you are plotting time. Where are you getting the x-axis `data` points that you already have?

Comment: @AlexW no i am not plotting time, but i don't know what should I do. I am plotting the percentage of each agent. I may have 2 agent, and I may have 11 agents.

Comment: @AlexW I am getting it from a web service in ajax call

Comment: What I am referring to is the mode for the x-axis is time. I'm still trying to figure out where your data is coming from. I would use [array push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to add data dynamically to your `data` array.

Answer (score 0):

When using `$.plot(holder, data, chartOptions);`, save the plot with a variable.

Declare `var plot;` globally,

and then call like this: `plot = $.plot(holder, data, chartOptions);`.

You can grab the data from the plot like this:

```
var datasets = [];
var xData = [];

datasets = plot.getData();    //this returns an array of all datasets

//goes through each series of data
for (var i = 0; i < datasets.length; i++){
    //picks the series with label of "label 1"
    if (datasets[i].label == "label 1"){
        //copies x coordinates from the series into xData
        for (var j = 0; j < datasets[i].data[j].length; j++){
            xData.push(datasets[i].data[j][0]);               //if you want y coords, use datasets[i].data[j][1]
        }
    }
}
```